# Jquery Datatable issue with ajax call to spring boot

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

I am following this jquery plugin https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-jquery-datatables-a2e816e2b5e9

I am having issue getting data from backed(Java rest api).

here is my html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fw-widget" id="table3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ids</th>
       <th>user</th>
       <th>title</th>
       <th>body</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Here is my js code ,

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
var table = $('#table3').DataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,
             "ajax": {
                    "url": "/employees",
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
               "aaData":"data",
                "order": [
                    [ 0, "asc" ]
                    ],
                "Columns": [
                      { "data": "Id"},
                      { "data": "Name" },
                      { "data": "lastName" },
                      { "data": "totalTime" },
                      { "data": "todaysDate" },
                      { "data": "taskDetails" }
                ]
         });
    });
    
    </script>
```

backend controller in java,

```
@RestController
public class TimeSheetAPI {
    
    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;
    
    
    @Autowired
    CredService cService;

    @RequestMapping(path="/employees", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(Principal principal){
        Cred user = cService.findByUserName(principal.getName());
        List<Employee> employeedetails = someService.findEmployeeDetails(user);
        return employeedetails ;
    }
}
```

Now i tested my api with postman and its working fine. but when i run above code , ajax call dont work.

What am i doing wrong if there is a better approch then please mention it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your URL. Try like bellow

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var ajaxUrl = /*[[ @{'/employees'} ]]*/;


$(document).ready( function () {
var table = $('#table3').DataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,
             "ajax": ajaxUrl,
               "aaData":"data",
                "order": [
                    [ 0, "asc" ]
                    ],
                "Columns": [
                      { "data": "Id"},
                      { "data": "Name" },
                      { "data": "lastName" },
                      { "data": "totalTime" },
                      { "data": "todaysDate" },
                      { "data": "taskDetails" }
                ]
         });
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```